# macOS Mojave: Command + Shift + 4, screenshot not getting saved anymore

Tags: macos, mojave, screen-capture

When I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> and take a screenshot, the screenshot shows as a thumbnail at bottom right of the screen.

If I continue working, the screenshot is not saved. I have to double-click on the thumbnail, open it in Preview & save it.

How do I save the screenshot immediately like it used to?

The [answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297809/297469) doesn't really apply as I don't see a Touch Bar.

Comment: On mine the thumbnail saves to the desktop if left alone...

Comment: Just looked at the help file for the screenshot app and found out that one can drag  the thumbnail directly into a document before it gets saved.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen capture utility no longer saves to Desktop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125046/screen-capture-utility-no-longer-saves-to-desktop)

Answer (score 12):

Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to invoke the screen capture app. Click on Options and check if the **Save to** location is set correctly.

[image]

Comment: This option looks good, and checking the options the screenshot is set to save to Desktop, but it never ends up there. This has been going on for about 2 weeks. No OS updates in that time.

Comment: Any advice Nimesh? I think the behaviour changed during an OS update.

Comment: @Insight AFAIK it didn't. What's the release of macOS that you are running? Maybe some configuration changes got made.

Comment: Running 10.15 Catalina Beta. "Show Floating Thumbnail" was selected. Deselecting it, I can see the screenshot gets saved to Desktop, but it immediately automatically gets deleted every time some how.

Comment: @Insight Can't comment on behavior in Catalina ATM. One, it's currently in beta and things are liable to break. Two, I am not running it on any of the machines. Advise you to wait till the public release is out later in Fall.

Comment: OK, cheers Nimesh.

Comment: The process screencaptureui fails to write the screenshot to the Desktop check this answer. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368703/49648

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the advice by Nimesh Neema -- press Command + Shift 5 to gain access to the settings -- I would also unselect "Show Floating Thumbnail" to have your screenshots go directly to the selected destination (eg Desktop). The nice thing about the floating window is that you can often drag it directly into an app without having to go find it in the desktop.

Comment: Cmd+Shift+4 just gives me the cursor to select a portion of the screen...

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped the instruction. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks Brad. "Show Floating Thumbnail" was selected. Deselecting it, I can see the screenshot gets saved to Desktop, but it immediately automatically gets deleted every time some how.